# Hiding Empty ttk Notebook Tabs with Grid vs Pack

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

At https://github.com/muhammeteminturgut/ttkScrollableNotebook there is a lovely demo of effectively adding scrolling tabs at the top of a notebook.  But there is actually a notebook elements, one on top of the other.

```
if self.useGrid:
    self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    leftArrow.grid(row=0, column=0)
    rightArrow.grid(row=0, column=1)
    slideFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NE)
    self.notebookContent.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
else:
    leftArrow.pack(side=LEFT)
    rightArrow.pack(side=RIGHT)
    slideFrame.place(relx=1.0, x=0, y=1, anchor=NE)
    self.notebookContent.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

I am trying to convert it to use grid instead of pack, but when using grid the empty tabs of the bottom notebook are displayed.  Somehow they are hidden when using pack.  What is the difference here?  How can grid reproduce pack's functionality here?

Comment: When I try to use  your code in place of similar code in the `ScrollableNotebook` class I get errors. It seems like you must have changed more code than just this. For example, when you use `grid` it complains that you can't use it because some other widgets (specifcially, `bottomTab`) uses `pack` and it has the same parent as `leftArrow` and `rightArrow`.

Comment: Yes, I gathered all pack/place commands into the if/else-statement shown above so you would have to do similarly.